# Why is displayStart (Datatable 1.10) not working for me?

Tags: node.js, angular, datatables-1.10

I am using Datable (1.10.3) and whatever value I set in the `diplayStart` field, the `start` parameter of the server request always goes as 0.
Here is my code:

```
    this.table = $('#table').DataTable({
      displayStart: 100,
      order: [[0, 'desc']],
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      searching: true,
      pageLength: 50,
      searchDelay: 1000,
      language: {
        lengthMenu: 'Show _MENU_ records per page'
      },
      dom: '<"top"il>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
      ajax: {
        url: <url>,
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
          authorization: <token>
        },
        data: function (d) {
          //setting request data
        },
        dataSrc:  (json) =>{
          return json.data;
        },
        error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
          if (xhr.status + '' === '401') {
            location.href = '/';
          }
        }
      },
      columns: this.getColumns(),
      
      drawCallback: function () {
        //some operations
      }
    });
```

It seems to work fine if I initialise the table like the older version, like this:
`this.table = $('#table').dataTable({...`
But this initialisation breaks other preexisting function calls (like `search` and `row`) in the code.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if displayStart works with server side.
I realize this is not an ideal solution if you dont find any other you can override the pipeline method forcing it to use whatever you want:

```
$.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
    return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
            request.start = 20;     
            return $.ajax( {
                "type":     opts.method,
                "url":      opts.url,
                "data":     request,
                "dataType": "json",
                "success":  drawCallback
            } );
    }
};
```

Taken the example from: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

Comment: i am having a problem based on this solution. setting the start value gets me the value required page values. but in this case the page number starts from 1, leaving no way to get the previous results.

can you please suggest anything better?